# How can I get a me.com e-mail address?

Tags: mail.app, email, mobileme, icloud

Was this a service only offered with Apple's Mobile Me? Is there anyway I can still get an e-mail address ending in @me.com?

Comment: The answers below appear to be old (before iCloud was released) so are based on some guess work... Can anyone please update whether one can still get @me.com email id, I'm unable to find a way.

Comment: I found a way and have added it as answer below.

Answer (score 7):

It's basically not possible to make a new MobileMe account while the transition to iCloud is happening. There are some loopholes (like adding a new account under an existing Family account) - but most will have to wait until iCloud is released. The official word on that is a vague - in the fall of 2011.

From the Apple preview [page](http://www.apple.com/icloud/features/contacts-calendar-mail.html) covering Contacts, Calendar and Mail as part of iCloud:

> **Mail that delivers. Free.**
>
> When you set up iCloud, you get a free me.com
> email account. iCloud automatically
> pushes new email messages to all your
> devices, so your inbox is up to date
> everywhere you check it. And iCloud
> keeps all your folders in sync, no
> matter which device you’re using.

That was posted June 6, 2011, and I think that's pretty definitive. Free me.com accounts for all. It's unclear if you can get a new one *today*, but when iCloud opens to the public, you'll be able to sign up for one.

The sign-up page for MobileMe was disabled when iCould was announced at WWDC. People with unredeemed paid memberships can request a refund as they can no longer create a new account. Also, the free trials are suspended - presumably until iCloud opens this fall. The [MobileMe transition FAQ](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4597) documents this in detail and should be updated if things change before iCloud details are released.

The only way to get an account is if you already have a Family Pack with unallocated sub accounts. It is not clear if and how that sub account will transition to iCloud, but that may be an option for some to establish MobileMe email after June 6, 2011 and before iCloud opens for business.

Comment: "Free me.com accounts for all." with "all" meaning every one who owns an iGadget or a mac with OSX 10.7 (or later).

Comment: Possibly true (We don't yet know if Windows users with Safari or iTunes but no iGadgets will be able to sign up for iCloud), but I think that on AskDifferent, that's not an very restrictive assumption. If people want free email that can do lots of other stuff, including excellent syncing capabilities for many platforms, there's always Google. I use MobileMe now for mail, calendar, and contact syncing, but NetNewsWire and Reeder use Google Reader as my canonical RSS store. And when we had Blackberries a few years ago, before we bought the iPhones, we used Google Sync.

Comment: @martin anyone with an Apple ID will be able to sign up for an iCloud account, so all you will need to do is go to https://appleid.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MyAppleId.woa/ and set one up.

Answer (score 7):

Definitive answer on this is now at [Apple's KB](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201771) as of 15 Jan 2015

*Extract:*

> - If you created an iCloud account on or after September 19, 2012, your email address ends with @icloud.com. Learn more about [@icloud.com mail addresses](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5441).
> - If you created an iCloud account before September 19, 2012, or moved to iCloud with an active MobileMe account before August 1, 2012, you have both @me.com and @icloud.com email addresses.
> - If you had a working @mac.com email address as of July 9, 2008, kept your MobileMe account active, and moved to iCloud before August 1, 2012, you can use @icloud.com, @me.com, and @mac.com email addresses with your iCloud account.
>
> In each case, you can sign in to iCloud with either your @icloud.com email address or the [Apple ID](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH2570) that you use with your iCloud account.
>
> If you created one or more [email aliases](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4897) for your account, be aware of the following:
>
> - You can [change or delete an email alias](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH2622), but if you delete an @mac.com or @me.com email alias, you can't add it back to your iCloud account.
> - You can't sign in to iCloud.com with an email alias. Sign in with your @icloud.com email address or the [Apple ID](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH2570) that you use with your iCloud account.

Answer (score 4):

You can actually just go into the "Mail, Contacts & Calendars" section of your system preferences on your Mac.  Click the add account option on the left and then click the iCloud option on the right, it will give you the option to generate a new apple ID account with an option to make it a free @me.com account.

Answer (score 3):

Steve Jobs mentions in WWDC 2011, that "We'll give you a me.com email address," when speaking about iCloud.  So - if your question was in reference to whether the @me.com addresses will disappear with the coming of the iCloud service, no, I don't think so.

Answer (score 2):

From [this Apple Support page](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4597):

> Can I create a new MobileMe account?
>   You can no longer create a new 60-day trial account or start a new subscription using a code contained in a MobileMe box. However, if you have a Family Pack subscription, you can still create new family member accounts.

Edit: I hadn't targeted the actual question very well: "How can I get a me.com e-mail address?".

Turns out, you only need to [create an Apple ID](https://appleid.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MyAppleId.woa/) using your an existing email address which you will need to verify; then using iOS 5, OS 10.7, or Windows Vista or later, and create an iCloud account which will include your choice of an available @me.com address.

Answer (score 1):

On a Mac running Lion or higher, click System Preferences, select iCloud.

If you have selected another account, logout.

Click on Create an Apple Id ... rest is self-explanatory and go through the steps.

Answer (score 0):

Ah hah! So I found a tricky way to get my me.com address. I downloaded the iOS 5 developer preview onto my iPad 2. The new iOS gives you the option to create a me.com e-mail address.

Comment: These accounts could be marked as developer sandbox only similar to Game Center accounts that were all mass deleted just before the go-live date for the general public. Use caution unless you have information that these are not just test accounts and will actually be migrated if that matters to you.

Comment: @bmike: Per your flag, developer questions are okay up to the point of asking about actual code. The lingering question is really how much traction these will get over time (which so far isn't much, but there really isn't another place to ask them. SO will close stuff like this and Programers is for subjective questions).

Comment: http://developer.apple.com has discussions for anything relating to beta software and NDA material and iCloud beta - perhaps you meant no other place on SE.

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for a way to get @me email id and finally after a lot of search found a way [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3381537?start=0&tstart=0)

> go into the iCloud settings on your Mac and check Mail, you will be
>   prompted to create a @me.com address.

I'm not sure whether there is any other way to create @me address from me.com or icloud.com but the above worked for me!

Answer (score -1):

I don't recall seeing it mentioned during the process of signing up for iCloud but @me.com addresses/aliases are automatically created alongside your @iCloud.com email address.

For instance, if John Doe created an iCloud account today and subsequently obtained his John.Doe@iCloud.com email address he could also receive email sent to John.Doe@me.com without doing any extra work on his end.

tl;dr - If you already have an @iCloud.com email address you can automatically receive email sent to the same address ending in @me.com.

Comment: How does this differ from other answer's e.g. Atul Goyal's and jaideep's and Diana's

Comment: @Mark The difference is none of their answers explain that me.com addresses are still available as an alias.  If an end user walks through the steps in any of their explanations they're greeted with options all ending with iCloud.com addresses.  Technically they are correct, these are valid methods for obtaining a me.com/icloud.com address, but they don't explain that the iCloud address can use the Me address as an alias.